# Simplification of for loop

Tags: python

You don't need to understand everything in the code below, all that I want you to do is make it more efficient. If you don't know what I mean, here's an explanation:
Do you see how I always have `index_1`, `index_2`, `index_3`, `index_4` as variables?
There surely must be a better way to do this than manually writing them down, but I am not sure how.
(`categorys_num` is an object, and `categorys_N.options` is a list.)

```
for index_1 in range(1, len(categorys_1.options)):
    categorys_1.options[index_1].click()
    print(categorys_1.options[index_1].text)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
    for index_2 in range(1, len(categorys_2.options)):

        categorys_2.options[index_2].click()
        print('  ' + str(categorys_2.options[index_2].text))
        time.sleep(0.3)
        
        for index_3 in range(1, len(categorys_3.options)):

            categorys_3.options[index_3].click()
            print('    ' + str(categorys_3.options[index_3].text))
            time.sleep(0.3)
            
            for index_4 in range(1, len(categorys_4.options)):

                categorys_4.options[index_4].click()
                print('      ' + str(categorys_4.options[index_4].text))
                time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Are `categorys_N.options` lists?

Comment: if I'm saying `variable[index]`, it makes a lot of sense for it to be a list

Comment: Not sure why other users have downvoted your question but I certainly can tell you why I did. Are you sure this is the tone and language you want to use when asking other people for help with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the lists and operate off the items in it as that's all you're doing:

```
for op1 in categorys_1.options:
    op1.click()
    print(op1.text)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
    for op2 in categorys_2.options:
        op2.click()
        print('  ' + str(op2.text))
        time.sleep(0.3)

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for *recursion*:

```
def f(prefix,cats):
    if len(cats)<1:
        return
    for x in cats[0]:
        x.click()
        print(prefix + x.text)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        f( prefix + '  ', cats[1:] )

f('',[category_1.options, category_2.options, category_3.options, category_4.options])
```